# Discord python bot - massban

Tags: python, discord.py

I made this command for my discord bot to massban members that are in and without the server. Turns out that I get an error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an
exception: HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid
Form Body In message_id: Value "757201002062544946 759785520065806366"
is not snowflake.
```

The IDs listed are real IDs and are my test subjects for the massban command.

Here is my code

```
@client.command(aliasas=['mb'])
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members = True)
async def massban(ctx, *, ids:str):
    await ctx.channel.fetch_message(ids)
    ids = ids.split(" ")
    success = 0
    for id in ids:
        await client.guild.ban(int(id), delete_message_days=0)
        success += 1
    await ctx.send("Massbanned " + str(success) + " member/s.")
```

Comment: But the IDs are strings, not integers, and they're a joined string, i.e `"9187398 98173981"` not a list of strings, i.e `["1123132123", "981723"]`, it should be a list of integers

Comment: I think they split the `ids` string so it gives a list of the IDs separated by spaces (line 5).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@client.command(aliasas=['mb'])
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members = True)
async def massban(ctx, *, ids:str):
    list_of_ids = ids.split(' ')
    success = 0

    for id in list_of_ids:
        id = client.get_user(int(id))
        await ctx.guild.ban(id, reason='You were mass-banned')
        success += 1

    await ctx.send("Massbanned " + str(success) + " member/s.")
```

First off, what was causing you the error was this line: `await ctx.channel.fetch_message(ids)`, which wasn't necessary in your case.

Second, `await client.guild.ban(int(id), delete_message_days=0)` isn't exactly the way you ban a member. The attribute `client` doesn't take in `guild`. Instead, it should be `ctx.guild.ban()`.

Finally, the `id` variable isn't directly converted to a discord user when you turn it to an integer. You should, in most cases, use the `client.get_user(id)` method to render a user object.

So in this case, you would use the command like: `[prefix]massban id1 id2 id3 ...`

Comment: Ohhh I see I see and yeah the command is supposedly like that, I've tried that and unfortunately I get this error in the cmd:

`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id' `

And isn't `delete_message_days=0` a way to ban members that are not in the server? It is also one of the things I wanted

Answer (score 0):

I'm gonna answer my own question over here since I figured it out. First I converted the list of strings to `int` since it causes errors then used that `int list` to use the `foreach loop` in fetching/getting their ids and banning them one by one. This also applies to users outside the guild.

```
    @client.command(aliasas=['mb'])
    @commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
    async def massban(ctx, *, ids:str):
        list_of_ids = ids.split(' ')
        list_of_idsx = list(map(int, list_of_ids))
        success = 0
    
        for id in list_of_idsx:
            user = await client.fetch_user(id)
            await ctx.guild.ban(user, delete_message_days=0)
            success += 1
    
        await ctx.send("Massbanned " + str(success) + " member/s.")
```